# Issue with iterating through child nodes of XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I want to iterate through child nodes of the main node of XML in Ruby, but the output I get is something not expected.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
    <sub>
      <a></a>
      <b></b>
    </sub>
</main>
```

I need to iterate through child nodes of "sub":

```
require 'nokogiri'
f = File.open('test.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

main_node = doc.xpath("//main/sub").first
subnode = main_node.children

subnode.each do |node|
    puts "#{node.name}"
end
```

I am expecting output as:

```
  a
  b
```

But what I get is

```
text
a
text
b
text
```

Comment: Or is there some other means to iterate through child nodes?

Comment: Don't confuse using `search` or its act-alikes `css` and `xpath`, all of which return a NodeSet, and `at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` which return a Node. The "`at`" methods return the first node matching the selector and are equivalent to `search(...).first`. Use `at` or its siblings for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NOBLANKS parse option.

http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#parse_options

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f) do |config|
  config.noblanks
end
```

Comment: Explain *why* that works. It's important to understand.

Comment: @theTinMan It removes the blank nodes.But I am not sure how blank nodes are being inserted.If you know please add as a comment, it would be really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how blank nodes are being inserted.

Consider this simple example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body><p></p></body></html>
EOT

doc.at('p').next_sibling # => nil

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('p').next_sibling # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde488b63b4 "\n  ">
doc.at('p').next_sibling.to_html # => "\n  "
```

In non-formatted/non-prettified/squashed HTML, there usually isn't whitespace between nodes unless it's significant in text or necessary to be syntactically correct HTML; It isn't necessary for the browser or a parser otherwise.

We add whitespace to make it more readable for our eyes, but the embedded line-breaks and tabs/spaces used for indentation have to be accounted for somehow, so they're treated as text nodes. Normally we don't care because our navigation of the document to find particular nodes and their embedded content conveniently takes us around/past the "formatting nodes", but they still exist and they are significant for the structure of the document.